# Winforms C# application crash in one selecting combobox

Tags: c#, combobox

On selecting any items in the combo box, it is saying invalid argument. Value is not valid for length . Parameter name : length

This occurs in swedish os only but in englis OS of win 7 it is not.

I am aware that it could not be valid difference, but we just identified one difference between both the system (system where the application runs successfully and the other where it does  not )

Comment: Can you show the code that calls the method that says that the length value is not valid, and show where you get the value for that parameter?

Comment: What items does this combobox filled with ?

Comment: Can you show us your selected index changed event?

Comment: Please provide the faulting code as the information provided is not sufficient to assit you. The code populating the ComboBox and the SelectedIndexChange event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Its sounds to me like you have named a variable the same as a property, and it is overriding it. I would try adding a prefix to your variable names, or choosing less common ones.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had these two lines in the code which is called from "key_up" event .

Comment: "cmbControl.SelectionStart = actual.Length;cmbControl.SelectionLength = found.Length;"

Comment: You are sure actual.Length and found.Length always return appropriate values?